# Suggestions on how to draw a concentric spheres plot?

Tags: python, r

[image]

Hi,
I am interested in drawing a figure, in R or python, resembling the attached image, where the largest sphere represents the total and each of the smaller spheres represent a certain percentage of the total?

Comment: How would the reader interpret the percentages? By sphere volume? Diameter? Area of the circle when sliced through the centre? I don't think this is an effective or easily-interpreted visualisation. If I were looking at proportions of a total, I'd consider using a treemap.

Comment: The sphere volumes would represent percentages of the whole. Visually, this is easier for readers to get an idea about the proportions of these subpopulations.

Comment: If you search the Web for "visualize proportions", you'll find many references explaining how humans find it more difficult to compare relative areas than simpler measures, such as height. This also goes for 2D representations of volume. [Here are some visualisation ideas](https://datavizcatalogue.com/search/proportions.html) for proportions. Note that none of them use volume. I think you need to read up on data visualisation and get some idea of best practice.

Comment: Thanks neilfws for the link. I was specifically asking about this because it is a very common way by which many biologists depict reservoir size and scientists are used to seeing them. But I will consider the other options you alluded to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an implementation in R using the RGL package in R.  I realize this is a 5+ year question, but I was actually looking for this representation for a 3 domain mass transport visualization.  I tried closing them using a circle, but it got a bit complicated.
[image: Concentric spheres as RGL surfaces using R]

```
# Import the rgl package
library(rgl)

# Function to generate points for a sphere
create_sphere <- function(radius, num_points = 30) {
  theta <- seq(0, pi, length.out = num_points)
  phi <- seq(pi, 2*pi, length.out = num_points)
  x <- outer(radius * sin(phi), cos(theta), FUN = "*")
  y <- outer(radius * sin(phi), sin(theta), FUN = "*")
  z <- outer(radius * cos(phi), rep(1, num_points), FUN = "*")
  return(list(x = x, y = y, z = z))
}

# Create the concentric spheres with different radius
sphere1 <- create_sphere(radius = 5)
sphere2 <- create_sphere(radius = 40)
sphere3 <- create_sphere(radius = 60)

# Plot the concentric spheres
par3d(windowRect = c(20, 30, 420, 430))
surface3d(sphere1$x, sphere1$y, sphere1$z, color = "yellow", alpha = 1.0, shininess = 50)
surface3d(sphere2$x, sphere2$y, sphere2$z, color = "purple", alpha = 0.8, shininess = 50)
surface3d(sphere3$x, sphere3$y, sphere3$z, color = "blue", alpha = 0.8, shininess = 50)

# Set the point of view
view3d(theta=0, phi=30, fov=-60, zoom=0.8)

# Save the plot as an image
rgl.snapshot("half_spheres_concentric.png")
```

Comment: This is actually perfect Jose. I never figured out how to draw them and am sure someone will find this answer helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Research in perception suggests that percentages of a whole are probably most effectively visualised with stacked bar charts - the cartesian counterpart of pie charts. If your data has a hierarchy as well, then I agree with neilsfw in using a treemap.